# Cordova exec function not defined in cordova-2.1.0

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i was trying to implement a push notification plugin in simple example. when i run my app and when i call cordova.exe() from my index.html via index.js i get this error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cordova is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/PushPlugin.js
```

i use `cordova-2.1.0.js` ! but when i changed it to `cordova-3.0.0.js` i get this information in the logCat consol :

```
exec() call to unknown plugin: PushPlugin
```

that's mean that any "PushPlugin" not declared in res/xml/config.xml file, but i put this line in my config.xml :

```
    <plugins>
...
      <plugin name="Plugin" value="com.example.Plugin"/> 
...
    </plugins>
```

so can u help me and gave me some solutions of this kind of problems ?

Comment: Are you sourcing in Cordova before the plugin that depends on it?

Comment: do u mean by sourcing that adding <gap:plugin name="com.mwa.GCMPlugin" version="3.0.0" /> to the www/config.xml file or to the res/xml/config.xml file

Comment: No, I mean are you sourcing in `cordova-3.0.0.js` before `PushPlugin.js` in your markup? Literally `<script src="path/to/cordova-3.0.0.js"></script><script src="path/to/PushPlugin.js"></script>`

Comment: yeah i did ! always the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i got the same error before , and you said that you have changed to cordova-3.0.0 ! so you upgraded your application from cordova-2.1.0.js to cordova-3.0.0 !

so you have to replace this line in the config.xml :

```
<plugins>
    <plugin name="Plugin" value="com.example.Plugin" />
<plugins>
```

by :

```
<feature name="Plugin">
            <param name="android-package" value="com.example.Plugin" />
        </feature>
```

because you have upgraded the application to cordova-3.0.0, so you have to change the plugin declaration syntax in the res/xml/config.xml